# On an implication of Kronecker-Weber therorem

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assuming Kronecker-Weber therorem:

> Any abelien extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a subextension of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}$

Then we have a surjective homomorphism

$$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*=\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$$

I want to show that if $p$ is a prime not dividing $n$, then $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is not unramified at $p$. But I don't see how to use the "$p$ not dividing $n$" condition correctlly.  Could you give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$ is unramified at all primes $p\nmid n$? A subextension of an unramified extension is unramified.

Comment: @Mathmo123 , thanks for your comment, but I still don't see how to show $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is unramifed at $p$....

Comment: OK! Do you know anything about the ramification of cyclotomic extensions, e.g. when $n = p$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 when $n=p$, it seems that $p$ will ramifies, but I don't know the proof.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I find a proof in Washington's book, and the proof uses some property about ramification and discriminant.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Actually I see this statement firstly in Kedlaya's CFT notes, where the author just brushes over it without explaining anything, which makes me think it's just a obvious thing to everyone except me :-)

Comment: The usual strategy is to show that the discriminant of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)$ is a power of $p$, and then to apply the theorem that a extension is ramified at $p$ if and only $p$ divides the discriminant.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thanks for your help, I will look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase "is not unramifed at $p$" should be "is not ramified at $p$" or "is unramified at $p$", but *not* what you wrote.

As for the question itself, here is a general result that is quite useful: if $K$ is a number field and we can write $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer that is the root of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbf Z[x]$, then for each prime $p$ such that $f(x) \bmod p$ is separable, $p$ is unramified in $K$.  Apply this to your situation with $K = \mathbf Q(\zeta_n)$ and $f(x) = x^n - 1$.

Twp things worth noting: (1) we are *not* requiring $f(x)$ to be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf Q$, although the hypothesis on $f(x)$ above does pass to that minimal polynomial since it is factor of $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z[x]$, and (2) there is no claim that the converse is true. It is definitely false in general that when $f(x) \bmod p$ is not separable that $p$ has to be ramified.  For example, take $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{5})$ and $f(x) = x^2 - 5$. We have $x^2 - 5 \equiv (x-1)^2 \bmod 2$, but $2$ is unramified in $K$. The ring of integers of $K$ is *not* $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{5}]$, but is a larger ring.